# How to install photon ML in Anaconda?

Tags: python, apache-spark, anaconda

I am using Anaconda and am trying to install photon ML.

I tried typing "pip install git+git://github.com/linkedin/photon-ml.git" at the command prompt in my Anaconda terminal but received the following error: "No such file or directory: C:\users\paul_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-0y0kbxk_\setup.py".

I also tried downloading the zip file (photon-ml-master.zip) and typing "pip install C:\Users\Paul_\Downloads\photon-ml_master.zip" at the command prompt in my Anaconda terminal but received the following error: "No such file or directory: C:\users\paul_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-0azr963g\setup.py".

Can somebody help me understand how to install this?

Thanks.

Comment: I took a quick glance at the github page, is using pip part of the official installation instructions?

Answer (score 0):

pip seems to be trying to find a file named `setup.py`, which isn't present. Follow the file path to `setup.py` to see if it is there and if not, try uninstalling and reinstalling pip. Uninstall pip using:

```
pip uninstall pip
```

Then download `get-pip.py` [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). Then navigate to the folder you downloaded it to using `cd` and then run this command to install:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Daniel.  I tried to follow your directions and this is what happened.  1) apt-get remove didn't work (I am in Windows 10 and apt seems to be for Linux).  So, I just used "pip uninstall pip" and it worked.  2) I downloaded get-pip.py successfully.  3) Then I tried "pip install git+git://github.com/linkedin/photon-ml.git" again and got same error message as originally.  4) I went to the folder where setup.py could not be found and discovered that the folder does not exist.  Additional help would be appreciated.  Sorry for the formatting.  Don't know how to add a blank line

Comment: @Paul_S When you download a package you need a `setup.py` file, which by the looks of the GitHub repository, there is no setup.py. Try downloading the zip file and then extract the files and put them into a folder. Then in your code where you want to import the module, type `import sys` then `sys.path.append('C:\\...')` with the path to the folder with the Photon ML files, then you can `import` the module you need from there and hopefully it will work.

Comment: Hi Daniel.  I followed your suggestions.  Still no luck.  There's a tutorial at [link](https://github.com/linkedin/photon-ml/wiki/Photon-ML-Tutorial) . The tutorial requires installing Docker Desktop.  I was able to install it but it gave me an error when I tried to run it.  FYI, I am trying to use Photon's GAME module.  I don't know what to try next.

Comment: @Paul_S In terms of the Docker Engine, maybe there is something you could try [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-for-windows-wont-launch/15725/11). If not, continuing from my previous suggestion, maybe you could try putting your script where you are using the Photon GAME module inside the folder with the Photon ML files that you extracted from the zip file, and then just `import` the module like normal in your script. The module (assuming it's there in the Photon ML files) should be able to be imported due to being in the same directory.

Comment: I tried the ideas about the Docker Engine in the link that you provided.  No luck.  I'd like to try your suggestion about "putting [my] script... inside the folder with the Photon ML files".  Would this work if I am running a Jupyter notebook?  If so, how?

Comment: @Paul_S I'm not familiar with using Jupyter notebook, but I'd imagine you should be able to save the notebook to the folder like I said just like any python script, so you can directly import the module.

Comment: I got the Docker Tutorial to work.  I think that rebooting made it work.  I was able to run Photon ML inside the docker.  Thanks for your help, Daniel.

Comment: @Paul_S No problem, glad you got it working in the end.